# Wagtail add bulk actions to ModelAdmin IndexView

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I would love to add custom [bulk actions](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/extending/custom_bulk_actions.html) to a `ModelAdmin` index view. **Is that possible** already or a feature request potentially? The `ModelAdmin` module’s `IndexView` is great to filter a larger number of pages. I would love to select a bunch of these pages and start a custom bulk action like "publish", "unpublish" or "add to another page".

Alternatively I could try to add more attributes/columns to the page [Explorer](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/editor_manual/finding_your_way_around/the_explorer_page.html), which already offers these bulk actions. But the `ModelAdmin` module was added to Wagtail to do exactly that. So I think, that adding bulk actions to the `ModelAdmin` is the way to go.